How to use gitlab runner to send jobs to specific servers
I have multiple web applications. Each one is deployed on a different server because they need a specific environment. I'll figure out how to use containers eventually, just not now. I've figured out that if I create one runner per server and use tags on each runner, I can specify what deploy job go to what server.
For example, I have a server that has an ip address that ends in 17 so I gave it's associated runner the tag 17. Now my runner will pick up the job, go onto the 17 server using the shell executor, build and deploy the project.
Is there a better way to do this? Is there a better way to build and deploy projects to specific servers using gitlab runner? I don't know how to use docker containers yet, so it's very important that each project deploys to a server with the right environment.

You could use ssh to transfer files and run commands on the remote server instead of using a GitLab runner.

I thought about this, but the issue is that in my particular case, it's very slow/expensive to transfer files from my local desktop to a remote server because that's the way my organization is set up.
I could, however, use ssh to send commands to a remote server to build and deploy, but at that point I might as well just use gitlab runner to run shell commands
